# Finding Handle of a control inside a window

Tags: python, winapi

Given the handle to a parent window, How can I get the handle of a button inside this window?

I'm using `win32api.sendMessage( )` to pass values to a window. I want to use `BM_CLICK` to click on the button in question.

```
import win32api
import win32gui
import win32con

#get handle of the window I want

hwnd=win32gui.FindWindow(0,"SOME TITLE")

#btnHnd= (NEED CODE HERE TO GET THE HANDLE OF THE BUTTON INSIDE hwnd)

win32api.SendMessage(btnHnd, win32con.BM_CLICK, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
btnHnd= win32api.FindWindowEx(hwnd, 0 , "Button", "#Title")
```

is the way to find the handle of the child window, provided the button is a direct child of the parent, not just a descendent

Comment: For me this returns the following error: `AttributeError: module 'win32api' has no attribute 'FindWindowEx'`

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10, using Python 3.9 and `pywin32-306`, I had to do the following:

```py
import win32api
import win32gui
import win32con

# Get window handle
window = win32gui.FindWindow(0, "Window title")

# Get button handle
button = win32gui.FindWindowEx(window, 0, None, "Button title")

# Sent click
win32api.SendMessage(button, win32con.BM_CLICK, 0, 0)
```