# How to emulate button click with Python and winapi?

Tags: python, winapi

I am copletely new to winapi, and I have a window of a (proprietary) software. The task is to locate button in it and to "click" it from within my Python program. This solution is nice, I'm able to obtain HWND of a target window:
[python win32gui finding child windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948964/python-win32gui-finding-child-windows)

This snippet also looks good:
[Finding Handle of a control inside a window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530302/finding-handle-of-a-control-inside-a-window)
but the title of the button is not known, in my case it has only an icon and a tooltip ("Reconnect").

So I need to know how to find required button element and emulate clicking it.

Thank you in advance.

Edit.
Finally I managed to solve the problem (in a bit naive way):

```
def reconnect(win_title):
    """
    This method accepts window's title,
    looks for the 'reconnect' button and
    'clicks' this button
    """
    # parent window
    hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(0, win_title)

    # fetch all children windows' hwnds
    # store them in a list
    inplay_children = []

    def is_win_ok(hwnd, *args):
        s = win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)
        inplay_children.append(hwnd)

    win32gui.EnumChildWindows(hwnd, is_win_ok, None)

    # obtain hwnd of "reconnect button",
    # its index == -3 (I guessed that) 
    reconn_button_hwnd = inplay_children[-3]

    # bring window to foreground
    win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(hwnd)

    # send click to "reconnect button"
    win32api.PostMessage(reconn_button_hwnd, win32con.WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 0, 0)
    win32api.PostMessage(reconn_button_hwnd, win32con.WM_LBUTTONUP, 0, 0)
```

I hope this shall be of use.

Comment: If you've got the HWND of the button concerned, you're most of the way there. You just need to get the size and location of the button, then you can use the `mouse_event` function (in user32.dll) to **(a)** position the cursor above the button, **(b)** depress the button and then **(c)** release the button. GetWindowRect is the one to use for the button size/position, since it gives you screen-coordinates, which you'll need for the mouse_event function, albeit after some trivial math. (the `mouse_event` function treats 0,0 as top left and 65535,65535 as bottom right)